# It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Во время работы в студии все хорошо работает, когда публикую сайт на сервер пишет вот такие ошибки  :

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 

Line 26:       </controls>
Line 27:     </pages>
Line 28:     <authentication>
Line 29:       <forms loginUrl="~/default.aspx" timeout="30" />
Line 30:     </authentication>
```

Сайт одностраничный, работает в локалке для изменения констант в БД, которые в свою очередь использует job. Формы авторизации нету. Когда удаляю эти строки из web.config идут следующие подобного рода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая ошибка возникает если вы просто скопировали ваше приложение в подпапку wwwroot или по назначили виртуальный путь.

Чтобы веб-приложение работало - его надо настроить в IIS именно как веб-приложение. Это можно сделать через диспетчер служб IIS (см. скриншоты).

Преобразование в веб-приложение обычной папки или виртуального каталога:

[image]

Добавление нового веб-приложения:

[image]

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Я не знал этого! Все работает!